# Linked List insertion using for loop in separate function

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, function-definition, insertion

I am learning how to program in C++, and have looked at linked lists. I have found many code snippets to get me started.

The code I am playing with is from studytonight. I understand how to insert nodes into a list. But what if I want to create a linked list and fill x-many nodes at once in a loop? The `for` loop in my `main()` works fine, but when I try turning it into a function, such as `arrayToList()`, I am running into problems.

The function would simply use the entries of an array and turn them into the data (like an index) and a second value stored in the node. Obviously, the function needs to return a list to continue any manipulation, like deleting or replacing, etc, but also needs to receive a list as a parameter as the created list inside won't exist outside this function. The call to traverse the list inside the `for` loop is just to highlight that inside the function that list isn't empty.

I am a little lost as to make the function work, and would appreciate any help regarding a method to iteratively add x-many at once nodes to a linked list. I hope I have explained my problem well enough.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int data;         // Data
    node *prev;      // A reference to the previous node
    node *next;     // A reference to the next node
    double x;
};

class Doubly_Linked_List
{
    node *front;      // points to first node of list
    node *end;       // points to first las of list
    public:
    Doubly_Linked_List()
    {
        front = NULL;
        end = NULL;
    }
    void add_front(int, double );
    void forward_traverse();
    void arrayToList(int[], int);

};

void Doubly_Linked_List :: add_front(int d, double x)
{
    // Creating new node
    node *temp;
    temp = new node();
    temp->data = d;
    temp->x = x;
    temp->prev = NULL;
    temp->next = front;

    // List is empty
    if(front == NULL)
        end = temp;
        
    else
        front->prev = temp;
        
    front = temp;
}

void Doubly_Linked_List :: forward_traverse()
{
    node *trav;
    trav = front;
    while(trav != NULL)
    {
        cout<<trav->data<<" (" << trav->x << " )" << endl;
        trav = trav->next;
    }
}

void Doubly_Linked_List :: arrayToList(int arr[], int n)
{
   Doubly_Linked_List list;
   for(int i=n-1; i>=0;i--)
   {
       cout << i << endl;
       list.add_front(arr[i], arr[i]);
       list.forward_traverse();
   }
}

int main()
{
    Doubly_Linked_List list;
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
//    for (int i= 1; i< 10; i++)
//    {
//        list.add_front(i, i*2);
//    }
    list.arrayToList(arr, n);
    cout << "after filling arrayList " << endl;
    list.forward_traverse();
}
```

Comment: So...what is the double x for (my brain not working)? cause you pass same arguments here `list.add_front(arr[i], arr[i]);`?

Comment: Hi, Asphodel. The double x is just a value. I thought of the nodes having an integer index ("data") and a value which belongs to it, which could be anything. The idea was to maybe loop through the list and search for a specific index to manipulate the value "x" later on.

Answer (score 0):

Your `arrayToList()` is creating and filling a local `Doubly_Linked_List` object named `list`, which is a separate object from the `list` in `main()`.  Creating a local object is fine (it is good for exception safety), but `arrayToList()` is then discarding that local object and not assigning its data to the object that `arrayToList()` was actually called on.  That is why your call to `forward_traverse()` in `main()` does not see anything changed.

Try this instead:

```
#include <utility>

void Doubly_Linked_List :: arrayToList(int arr[], int n)
{
   Doubly_Linked_List list;
   for(int i=n-1; i>=0;i--) {
       list.add_front(i, arr[i]);
   }

   // add this
   std::swap(front, list.front);
   std::swap(end, list.end);
}
```

Otherwise, get rid of the local `list` and modify the data in `this` instead:

```
void Doubly_Linked_List :: arrayToList(int arr[], int n)
{
   // optional: clear the called-on object first, if needed...
   // clear(); // <-- add this method to Doubly_Linked_List...

   for(int i=n-1; i>=0;i--) {
       add_front(i, arr[i]);
   }
}
```

Otherwise, change `arrayToList()` to be `static`, and then have it return a new `Doubly_Linked_List` object (just make sure you also implement a copy constructor, copy assignment operator, and destructor, per the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)):

```
class Doubly_Linked_List
{
...
    // implement these!
    ~Doubly_Linked_List();
    Doubly_Linked_List(const Doubly_Linked_List &);
    Doubly_Linked_List& operator=(const Doubly_Linked_List &);

    // and change this
    static Doubly_Linked_List arrayToList(int[], int);
...
};

Doubly_Linked_List Doubly_Linked_List :: arrayToList(int arr[], int n)
{
   Doubly_Linked_List list;
   for(int i=n-1; i>=0;i--) {
       list.add_front(i, arr[i]);
   }
   return list;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    Doubly_Linked_List list = Doubly_Linked_List::arrayToList(arr, n);
    cout << "after filling arrayList " << endl;
    list.forward_traverse();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Remi! You explanation and link helped a lot. Sadly I get an error message from clang when trying your last suggestion:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Doubly_Linked_List::~Doubly_Linked_List()", referenced from:
      Doubly_Linked_List::arrayToList(int*, int) in studytonight-d58fec.o
      _main in studytonight-d58fec.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Will figure this out, but thank you so much!

Comment: @curious_s I gave you the *declarations* for those methods, but I left it as an exercise for you to *implement* them. Then that error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function should be declared like

```
void arrayToList( const int[], size_t );
```

and the function can be defined the following way if to take into account this commented statement in main

```
//        list.add_front(i, i*2);

void Doubly_Linked_List :: arrayToList( const int arr[], size_t n )
{
    while ( front )
    {
        node *current = front;
        front = front->next;
        delete current;
    }
    end = nullptr;

    for ( size_t i = n; i != 0; i-- )
    {
        add_front( arr[i-1], 2 * arr[i-1] );
    }
}
```

Though it would be better to declare the function at least like

```
void arrayToList( const std::pair<int, double>[], size_t );
```